# outputBuffers returns null pointer although the frame is rendered on the screen, using MediaCodec in Android

Tags: android, media, bytebuffer, encoder, android-mediacodec

I am using the `MediaCodec` class to decode a .mp4 video using the code given in this [link](https://vec.io/posts/android-hardware-decoding-with-mediacodec).

I am able to get the rendered output on the screen, but when I try to access the `outputBuffers[outIndex]`, I get a null pointer error. I cannot figure out how to access the frame buffer to do some processing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected (albeit undocumented) behavior.  You can either send the output to a `ByteBuffer` or to a `Surface`, but not both.

Some additional examples that may be of interest are available [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).  If you decode to a `SurfaceTexture` you can render the texture twice, once to a `View` and once to a pbuffer surface.  You can either use `glReadPixels` to get the data and process it, or do your processing in a GLES shader.

If you extract to a `ByteBuffer`, you have to interpret the data yourself, which is difficult on devices that use a proprietary output format.  You'll note from the buffer-to-buffer CTS tests that some devices aren't checked because the format isn't known.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.I would actually like to access the buffer data, to convert it to OpenCV's Mat format and do some processing on it, and then render it to the screen. Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: You could render it to a pbuffer Surface, extract the pixels as RGB with `glReadPixels`, do your processing, and then convert the result back to a texture with `glTexImage2D`.  As of Android 4.3, there's no portable way to interpret the data in the `ByteBuffer`, so GLES is your best bet.

Comment: I've notice that if we want to render to a SurfaceTexture we need to use createInputSurface() which is available just from API level 18. So does it mean that if we want to break video to frames we can use the MediaCodec just from API level 18?

Comment: Rendering *to* a Surface was supported by the initial version of MediaCodec in API 16.  Rendering *from* a surface, via `createInputSurface()` was introduced in API 18.